# Don't push changes in files

Tags: git

There is a file which I want to push but without changes I'll do.

For example:

```
// config.js
"default text"
```

And I have to modify the `config.js`:

```
// config.js
"my modified text"
```

But when I push this branch on the remote branch, I wanna push just `"default text"`.

I tried `git rm --cached <file>` but it removes this file from remote branch.

Comment: Git doesn't push files. Git pushes *commits*. Commits contain files, but the choice here is not "push config.js" or "don't push config.js", it's "push this commit" or "push that commit". If the commit contains config.js, off it goes. If the commit doesn't contain config.js, the file isn't there—it's deleted in that commit—and off that commit goes.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Is there any group of files which won't be commited?

Comment: The files that will be in your next commit are the copies of the files that are in your index right now. To see it (this can be a long list!) use `git ls-files`. Normally Git doesn't say anything about the index contents *except* that `git status` will *compare* the files in the index to those in the current commit, and tell you if any are different: these are what is `staged for commit`. (After that, it compares the files in the index to the files in the work-tree; any that are different are `not staged for commit`.)

Comment: Hence, what you'll need to do is make a *new* commit that has the *old* version of `config.js` in it, so that it's the same as in all the other older commits.

Comment: I commited all files. Is there an option to commit old version of one file from the previous commit?

Comment: There are few ways to achieve that. Cleaner one is to soft reset your commit will all files and re-do it more precisely.

Comment: I get it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged <filename>
```